# Proof of Set-theoretic limits

Tags: probability, self-study

I'm trying to solve this problem but there is something unsure about my solution.

Given

$lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}supA = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}   $

$lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}infA = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}   $

When $A_{k}$ is monotonically increasing, show that  $lim_{n=\infty}An = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ by showing $lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}supA = lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}infA $

To prove this I did,

$lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}supA = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}   = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(A_{n} \cup\dots\cup A_\infty)\}= (A_{1} \cup\dots\cup A_\infty)\cap(A_{2} \cup\dots\cup A_\infty)\cap \dots \cap A_{\infty} = A_{\infty} \cup \dots \cup A_{\infty} = A_{\infty} $

$lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}infA = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}    = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(A_{n} \cap\dots\cap A_\infty)\}= \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(A_{n} )\}= A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup  \dots \cup A_{\infty} = A_{\infty} $

Thus, $lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}supA  = lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}infA = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = A_{\infty}$

Even though this makes sense, however, it doesn't feel like it's mathematically correctly proved. Is this solution ok? or do I have to be mathematically more..rigorous? How should I do it?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: You should check your notation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing, defining $B_n=\cup_{k\geq n} A_k$, we have that 
$$B_1=B_2=B_3=\dots$$
Hence,
$$
  \limsup A_n := \cap_{n\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq n} A_k = \cap_{n\geq 1} B_n = B_1 = \cup_{k\geq 1} A_k =: \lim A_n \; . 
$$
On the other hand, $\cap_{k\geq n} A_k=A_n$, because $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing. Therefore,
$$
  \liminf A_n := \cup_{n\geq 1}\cap_{k\geq n} A_k = \cup_{n\geq 1} A_n =: \lim A_n\; . 
$$